# How convert timestamp to date on android?

Tags: android

I want convert timestamp to date and set time in this day to 12.00.
How can I do this?

If I use this:

```
Date date = new Date(event.getActionDate()*1000);
```

I can't set hour or minutes to this date, becouse methods for this operations are deprecated.

**Explanation:**

I have timestamp -

```
1461924872 // Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:14:32 GMT
```

I want **change hour** in this timestamp (**10**:14 to **00**.00).

Comment: Use a [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
long timeInMillis = 1461877200000l;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
System.out.println("Date1:"+calendar.getTime().toString());

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);  //For 12 AM use 0 and for 12 PM use 12.  
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);       
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Date date = calendar.getTime(); 
System.out.println("Date2:"+date.toString());
```

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko are not getting proper date object?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Have you passed `timeInMillis=1461924872000`?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko i request you to check it again. it's working fine for me.  i tested with `timeInMillis=1461924872000l` and final `date.toString()` print  `Fri Apr 29 00:00:00 IST 2016`

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko It's unix timestamps, multiply unix timestamp with 1000 and try again. Try `1461877200000`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();//get your local time zone.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);//set time zone.
String localTime = sdf.format(new Date(time) * 1000));
Date date = new Date();
date = sdf.parse(localTime);
```

Comment: And? How can I change hour for my time to 12 am?

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getDate(String timeStampStr){

try{
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date netDate = (new Date(Long.parseLong(timeStampStr)));
    return sdf.format(netDate);
}
catch(Exception ex){
    return dateInStr;
}
    }
```

let me know if it is working?